# Site Awards for Joomlers in Oceania

Tags: discussion

### [2020 Joomla Australia Site Awards](https://joomla.org.au/site-awards)

The **2020 Joomla Australia Site Awards** is a competition where individuals and agencies, within Oceania*, can submit their Joomla-powered website for judging by a panel of non-Oceanic judges for the chance to showcase their finest work or expose their brand, and increase their digital prestige.

Any individual or agency based in Oceania can submit a Joomla website as per the [Terms and Conditions](https://joomla.org.au/site-awards/terms-and-conditions).

Individuals or agencies can submit a maximum of one website per category. The categories are as follows:

- Community
- E-Commerce
- Marketing
- Blog
- Informational

How to enter:
**Get your entries in by Sunday 20/09/2020 11:59 pm AEST.** Please ensure that you read the [Entry Guidelines](https://joomla.org.au/site-awards/entry-guidelines) and [Terms and Conditions](https://joomla.org.au/site-awards/terms-and-conditions) before submitting your websites. Winners and Finalists will be announced on Tuesday 10/11/2020 at 10:00 am AEST.